# Azure DevOps Server 2019/2020 Access Levels Page Not Found

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I am running Azure DevOps Server 2019 cu7. When I click on the Access Levels link at the Project Collection level, I get a page not found error for ../_admin/_licenses.  I then upgraded my development farm to ADO Server 2020, and still have the same issue.
The app pool accounts are both System and I have added the System account to the iis_iusrs group.
Also, i get a page not found error when trying to hit the/_api/licenses/export api to try to get around the page not found error when using a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you do not have the permission `Edit Instance-level information`

Steps:

Open `Azure DevOps Server Administration Console`->click the option `Application Tier`->click the button `Administer Security`->select  `[Team Foundation]\Team Foundation Valid Users` and ensure the permission `Edit instance-level information` is set the **allow**. Then we could check the Access Levels page.

Result:

The permission is set to Deny

[image]

The permission is set to Allow

[image]

Comment: Since I am new and cannot upvote... Thank you Vito, your solution solved my problem on both the 2020 and 2019 farms.